# Count issue with MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, count

The following query works great in MS Access, however I actually wanted to get only the Main Project field plus the count for Name. Something like:

```
SELECT Sheet1.[Main project], Count(Sheet1.[Name]) AS Total
```

When I do that I get the following error:

"You tried to execute a query that does not include the specified expression 'Main project' as part of the aggregated function'

Am I doing something wrong in the join? Any idea what is not correct?

```
SELECT Sheet1.[Main project], Sheet1.[Main link], Sheet1.[Name]
FROM Sheet1
INNER JOIN Sheet1 AS Sheet1_1 

ON (Sheet1.[Main link] = Sheet1_1.[Main link]
AND Sheet1.[Main project] = Sheet1_1.[Main project])

WHERE Sheet1_1.[Name] ='0.4 Rollout plan approved'
AND Sheet1_1.[%compl#] = 100
AND (Sheet1_1.[Task class] <> '***Sammelvorgang' AND Sheet1_1.[Task class] <> '' AND  Sheet1_1.[Task class] <> 'M D-Muster')

AND Sheet1.[Main project] = 'AUDI AG, Ingolstadt'
AND (Sheet1.[Task class] <> '***Sammelvorgang' AND Sheet1.[Task class] <> '' AND  Sheet1.[Task class] <> 'M D-Muster')
AND (Sheet1.[Name] NOT LIKE '0.*' AND Sheet1.[Name] NOT LIKE '1.*')
AND Sheet1.[Start] < DateAdd("d",-7,Now())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT Sheet1.[Main project], Count(Sheet1.[Name]) AS Total
    FROM Sheet1
    GROUP BY Sheet1.[Main project]
```

Aggregate functions like `Count()` only work automatically when you want a total count of everything in the table.  If you want to break it down into more specific groupings, you need a `GROUP BY` statement to tell the database how to break it down.

Integrating that into your larger query should not be a problem: just note that the `GROUP BY` clause comes after the `WHERE` clause; thus you should add it at the end.